# Stock price logging function

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, function, finance

I have this function where the price of a stock gets logged in real time every 2 seconds and save it into a csv file however I cant see anything in the csv when I open it. What am I missing from the script?

```
import pandas as pd
import time
import urllib
import sys
import fix_yahoo_finance as yf

def stocks():

    # Enter stock symbol
    stock = input("Enter stock: ")

    # Name CSV file
    csvy= str(stock) + time.strftime('.%A.%d.%b.%Y').replace(' ', '') + ".csv" 
    csvy = csvy.replace(':' , '') 

    with open(csvy, 'w') as f: 
         sys.stdout = f 

         while 1 > 0: 

             print(yf.get_live_price(stock)) 

             time.sleep(2)

stocks()
```

Comment: You need to flush the buffer at some point; this often happens when the buffer is too full or you close the file.

Comment: Thank you...could you clarify how would it work to clear the buffer in this case? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You wrote:

> ```
>         print(yf.get_live_price(stock))
> ```

You want to additionally flush the buffer so your new text is immediately visible:

```
          print(yf.get_live_price(stock), flush=True)
```

Alternatively, consider assigning the live price to a temp variable,
and then outputting it twice, with `print()` and `f.write()`,
rather than assigning a new value to stdout.
Then you'd be able to flush them independently according to your need,
`f.flush()` or `sys.stdout.flush()`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment however it doesn't seam to be working based on what you've said.

Comment: When you delete the `sys.stdout = f` line, your while True loop prints no output?!?

Comment: yes tried to do as you said yet only made it giving me a syntax message.